# How to get the path where MSI is being installed within installer class

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have added an Installer class and within the class i'm overriding Install method. Within this method i want to get the path where MSI is being installed? (Directory user have chosen to install the application) ?

I tried the following and it gives me empty string,

```
string s = Context.Parameters["SrcDir"];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found how to get the target directory path from installer class

```
string installationPath = this.Context.Parameters["assemblypath"];
```

Comment: How do we get the current MSi path?

Comment: @Ranish What do you mean by current MSI path ?

Comment: Would be interesting if this can be set from the installer-class.

Answer (score 0):

Installation path that user choose in wizard

```
string installationPath = this.Context.Parameters["targetdir"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have iterated over all the available parameters to my installer class and found it only has:

```
Param: logfile, Value: 
Param: lo, Value: 1           // custom parameter set in custom install action
Param: action, Value: install
Param: installtype, Value: notransaction
Param: assemblypath, Value: D:\InstallerTrialHelper.dll
```

From it, I see we can use assemblypath directory to know which install directory is selected by user.